# iOS 5, Casting id to an Objective-C pointer with ARC

Tags: casting, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, ibaction

I was just starting a new iOS project with ARC and got stuck when I tried to cast my (id)sender of an IBAction to a Objective-C pointer. XCode was complaining: **Cast of Objective-C Pointer to UIButton* is idsallowed with ARC**. How do I do that correclty when using ARC?

```
- (IBAction)didPressButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;
}
```

It seems that the cast simply is unnecessary. Is it ok just to assign sender to a new pointer like that?!

```
UIButton *button = sender;
```

Cheers

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with that code. Are you sure that is exactly what you have and that the error is exactly on that line?

Comment: I agree with Firoze this cast is correct even in ARC so your error must be else where.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use `- (IBAction)didPressButton:(UIButton *)sender {...`